# Where is the System maintenance switch on HP ProLiant dl360 Gen 7

Tags: hp-proliant, boot, reset

I can not understand which is a possible switch, I could not even see pins. Please let me know if I am missing anything.

[image]

Comment: https://images10.newegg.com/User-Manual/User_Manual_59-107-023.pdf page 57

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Document "HP ProLiant DL360 G7 Server Maintenance and Service Guide" (Fourth Edition) location of System Switch marked as **2**

Item Number 2:
[image]